# save a field as JSON using factoryboy

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am trying to create an instance of the model in which one of the field is `JSONField`. When creating the instance of model via `factoryboy`, I want to save the field as JSONField in the test database. On simply passing the field as `JSON`,it gets stored in `Unicode` data type. I am stuck on this.

Comment: Hi, without seeing any code it is hard to answer this question. What factory_boy will do is simply build a big ``**kwargs`` dict and pass it to your Django Model; I'd advise first making some code example of what you want to happen without factory_boy, and only then building it through factory_boy.

Answer (score 17):

You can create dict data using a [`factory.Dict`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Dict). You can then control the final form of the data using the `dict_factory` attribute.

e.g. if you want to have `dict` data that is serialised to a JSON string, you can do something like this:

```
import json
import factory


class JSONFactory(factory.DictFactory):
    """
    Use with factory.Dict to make JSON strings.
    """
    @classmethod
    def _generate(cls, create, attrs):
        obj = super()._generate(create, attrs)
        return json.dumps(obj)


class BadgerFactory(factory.Factory):

    form_data = factory.Dict({
        'badger': ['stoat'],
    }, dict_factory=JSONFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried passing the value as a dictionary? It must be then converted to JSON.